# shallow or deep copy or the array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy, deep-copy

I am trying to solve a problem. I have a class with an int array prix. If I copy the object Test with the copy constructor. Will it make a deep or a shallow copy of the int array prix?

I cannot use any stl containers ((

```
Test
{
    Test(const char *id), id(id);
    {
        prix=new int[1];
    }
    Test(const Test & rhs): 
        id(rhs.id),
        prix(rhs.prix)
        {}
    //...
    const char *id;
    int * prix;
};
```

edit: I was wrong then, it is just a pointer.
How can I copy the array which is pointed?

Comment: Your class does not contain an array. It just contains a pointer. When you make a copy, only the pointer is copied.

Comment: But isn't the pointer like an array in this situation?

Comment: No, a pointer is just a pointer. You make it point to the first element of an array, but the pointer knows nothing about this. It just holds a value: the address of that first element. So, in terms of "deep" and "shallow" copies, your copy would be "shallow" (doing exactly the same as the compiler-generated copy constructor would.)

Comment: Confirm that `Test(const char *id), id(id);` is how you want the declaration to be.  It looks like this is an error.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and `std::string` and you'll avoid leaks and/or double-deletes you're setting yourself up with that class definition.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot :( I would be happy if I could use vectors but I cannot use stl containers.

Comment: Then tell your teacher that what he teaches is not considered idiomatic C++.

Comment: Is the array always 1 element long? If not, where do you store the length?

Comment: It is a part of a project where we have to deal with a bank database. We have to learn about deep and shallow copy. I use this pointer on array to store the difference of money on the account of a customer.

Comment: @FredOverflow The size is one at the begining but I reallocate it all the time needed (at every transaction).

Comment: It is impossible to reallocate if you don't know the size. Where do you keep it? Also, reallocating at every insertion is a common beginner's mistake that will make insertion O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the allocated array always has size equal to 1 then the constructor will look as

```
Test(const Test & rhs) : id( rhs.id )
{
    prix = new int[1];
    *prix = *rhs.prix;
}
```

Or if the compiler supports initializer lists then the constructor can be written as

```
Test(const Test & rhs) : id( rhs.id )
{
    prix = new int[1] { *rhs.prix };
}
```

Otherwise the class has to have an additional data member that will contain the number of elements in the array. 
Let assume that `size_t size` is such a data member. Then the constructor will look as

```
#include <algorithm>

//... 

Test(const Test & rhs) : id( rhs.id ), size( rhs.size )
{
    prix = new int[size];
    std::copy( rhs.prix, rhs.prix + rhs.size, prix );
}
```

You could write for example as

```
Test(const Test & rhs) : id( rhs.id ), size( rhs.size ), prix( new int[size] )
{
    std::copy( rhs.prix, rhs.prix + rhs.size, prix );
}
```

but in this case data member size has to be defined before data member prix in the class definition.

Comment: What makes you think `std::copy` is allowed when `std::vector` isn't? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow std::copy is not a comtainer. In fact it is a similar function as for example strlen.

Comment: I still bet the teacher won't accept anything inside the `std` namespace.

Comment: @FredOverflow It is not bad. In this case the author of the thread has to do something himself as to write a loop instead of the copy.